# No reconoce propiedad en modal Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy realizando un modal para edición de una fila de una tabla usando Angular, el archivo TypeScript (tournament.component.ts) lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
openDialogTournament(tournamentdialog: tournament){
    this.dialog.open(TournamentDialogComponent ,{
      width: '250px',
      data: tournamentdialog
    })
  }
```

Al momento de enviar la data con la información de la columna seleccionada me genera un error que no reconoce la propiedad, el error a detalle es el siguiente:
Property 'tournamentdialog' does not exist on type 'TournamentDialogComponent'.
<input matInput placeholder="Nombres" [(ngModel)]="tournamentdialog.nameTnt">

El archivo HTML (tournament-dialog.component.html) es el siguiente:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Nombres" [(ngModel)]="tournamentdialog.nameTnt">
</mat-form-field>
```

No me esta reconociendo el nombre de la data que le estoy enviando al HTML del modal, estoy usando la última versión de angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu `TournamentDialogComponent` tienes que inyectar el contenido de data usando el token `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`

```
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
...

export class TournamentDialogComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: tournament) { }
}
```

Y una vez hecho esto ya podrás acceder a su contenido desde el template a través de esta propiedad (la he llamado `data` en este caso, pero la puedes llamar como quieras)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Nombres" [(ngModel)]="data.nameTnt"> // <--
</mat-form-field>
```

un saludo

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, con eso ya pude obtener la data.